# How to uncheck a radio button by clicking on it a second time

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have been searching in a lot of topics but I haven't found anything that really correspond to my problem :

I want to make radio buttons uncheckable (i.e. uncheck a radio button by clicking on it when it's already checked).

I found some solutions using a hidden radio button as a temporary comparison object but this doesn't fits to my existing context, so I would like to do the same without another radio button.

I tried to simply test and change the status/value of the radio button on "onclick" event but it hasn't been very successfull...

Thanks in advance,
Clem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this sort of action is non-standard for radio buttons, but the poster requested the functionality.  The following is code that I've used in the past.  I've found it not to be the most optimized (assuming a large # of radio buttons), but I also haven't taken the time to do that optimization.

```
    //  Allow for radio button unchecking
$(function(){
    var allRadios = $('input[type=radio]')
    var radioChecked;

    var setCurrent = function(e) {
        var obj = e.target;
        radioChecked = $(obj).attr('checked');
    }

    var setCheck = function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'keypress' && e.charCode != 32) {
            return false;
        }
        var obj = e.target;
        if (radioChecked) {
            $(obj).attr('checked', false);
        } else {
            $(obj).attr('checked', true);
        }
    }

    $.each(allRadios, function(i, val) {
        var label = $('label[for=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']');
        $(this).bind('mousedown keydown', function(e){
            setCurrent(e);
        });

        label.bind('mousedown keydown', function(e){
            e.target = $('#' + $(this).attr("for"));
            setCurrent(e);
        });

        $(this).bind('click', function(e){
            setCheck(e);    
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 15):

That's not what radio buttons are. If you try to make this work, you will just confuse your users.

If you want something that can be checked and then unchecked, use a checkbox. Radio buttons are for selecting exactly one of some set of options.

Comment: What if he means to return it to its original, unselected state? A little confusing for the user still, but an understandable requirement.

Comment: Provide a reset button, perhaps, but un-checking the radio button is not how the rest of the world uses the radio-button control.

Comment: @box9 IMO it's a bug if there is such an "original, unselected state" i.e. if the radio buttons are presented to the user without one of them being selected to start out with. The point of a group of radio buttons is to require the user to choose one of the options.

Comment: I have design rules that force me to use radio buttons here. But what I want is just to let the possibility for the user to correct his answer by uncheking the selected radio button if he doesn't want to check any of them.

Comment: Add a "blank" option ("I don't know", "I don't want to answer"...).

Answer (score 6):

better so:

```
onclick="
var isChecked = $(this).attr('is_che');
if (isChecked) {
     $(this).removeAttr('checked');
     $(this).removeAttr('is_che');
}
else {
     $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
     $(this).attr('is_che', 'true');
}"
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right, it seems to be better for code optimization !